# The best way to add post configuration to an ECS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, user-data

I wonder what is the best way to add a post config step after instance creation when instance are automatically created by an ECS Cluster.

It seems there is no way to add user-data to ECS instance ?

Note : the instance are created automatically by the ECS Cluster itself.

### EDIT:

When using ECS, you configure a Cluster. While configuring the cluster you select instance type and other stuff (ssh key, ...) but there is nowhere to give some user-data to the instances that will be created by ECS. So the question is how to do some post-configuration on instances automatically created with ECS.

Comment: are you talking about an EC2 instance that joins an ECS cluster or an container that runs in the cluster?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, a bit confused, is it about ecs container instances or ecs task instances or ..... Or do you means you've setup an ec2 autoscaling group for your ecs cluster ?

Comment: I've added some explaination in the EDIT section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the management console, it's more of a wizard that creates everything needed for you, including the instances using the Amazon Linux ECS optimized AMI, and doesn't give you a whole lot of control beyond that.

To get more fine-grained control, you would have to use another method of creating your cluster, such as the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/).  These methods allow you (or require you, actually) to create each piece at a time.

Example:

```
$ aws ecs create-cluster --cluster-name MyEcsCluster
```

The above command creates you a cluster, and cluster only.  You would still have to create an [ECS task definition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/register-task-definition.html), [ECS service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/create-service.html)—although you could still use the management console for those—and (here's the real answer to your question) the EC2 instances which you want to attach to the cluster (either individually or through an [Auto Scaling group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html)).  You could create instances from the [Amazon Linux ECS optimized AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html), but also add user-data at that time to further configure them (you would also probably use the user-data in this scenario to create the `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` file to make sure it attaches to the ECS cluster you've created, e.g. `echo "ECS_CLUSTER=MyEcsCluster" > /etc/ecs/ecs.config`).

The short answer is, it's a more work to gain that sort of flexibility, but it is doable.

Edit: Thinking about it further, you could likely use the management console wizards to create everything once, then manually terminate the instances it created for the cluster (or, rather, delete the Auto Scaling group that creates them) and add your own.  This would save you some work.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. Looking forward I wonder if it is not possible to edit the Launch configuration automatically created by ECS Cluster initialisation to add some custom user-data script. I wonder if it breaks the models (and the underlying Cloudformation stack) or not.

Comment: @jmcollin92 While you can't edit a LC, you could replace the LC used by the ASG with your own (creating yours using the "Copy LC" action in the management console would be helpful).   This would get the ASG out-of-sync with the underlying CFN stack, so if you took actions through the ECS console that update the stack (like scaling up the number of instances), the ASG would revert back to using the original LC during the update.  Another option could be to copy the CFN template used by the ECS console, make your edits to it, and launch/manage your own stack for that.  AWS is pretty flexible!